# Python: TypeError: a float is required

Tags: arcpy, parameters

I have a python script with some parameters - see screen.
[image]

You see the last parameter is of type Double, default Value 0.

The code i have this:

```
Ausrichtung = float(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(9))
if Ausrichtung == '#' or not Ausrichtung:
    Ausrichtung = "0.0"
# maybe there is some useless ballast...it comes from an export from modelbuilder, and I am learning python now.

arcpy.AddMessage("Ausrichtung"+ Ausrichtung)
SteigungX = -math.sin(math.radians(Ausrichtung))
```

1) When I start the script - in the form i let for this parameter a 0, i always get:
Ausrichtung0.0
TypeError: a float is required
2) If I start the schript - with this parameter as a 5, it works.
3) When I replace last line with
    SteigungX = -math.sin(math.radians(float(Ausrichtung)))
   it works with all values, also with 0

I have several more parameters before this, and I can calculate with them.

Why is Zero so different?

Why do I have Ausrichtung in case 1) a 0, even when I use this float function?

AddMessage give a 0.0, so why still not recognized as float?

Answer (score 4):

Try replacing this:

```
Ausrichtung = float(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(9))
if Ausrichtung == '#' or not Ausrichtung:
    Ausrichtung = "0.0"
arcpy.AddMessage("Ausrichtung"+ Ausrichtung)
```

with this:

```
Ausrichtung = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(9)  # do not float() until you know it's numeric
if Ausrichtung == '#' or not Ausrichtung:
    Ausrichtung = 0.0  # a float, not a string
else:
    Ausrichtung = float(Ausrichtung)
arcpy.AddMessage("Ausrichtung {0}".format(Ausrichtung))
```

Comment: Thank you,  meanwhile I got more Ideas:  
- the "numeric" is given through the input form (i can´t enter nothing but a number in the input field) - so I can use float(arcpy.Getparameter(9))  
- I can use "GetParameter" (GetParameterAsText seems not to be necessary)  
- 0 means false, so it goes to the If Condition  
- you are right - not "0.0" but 0.0 makes a float  
  
This code works now and should be safe:  
Ausrichtung = float(arcpy.GetParameter(9))  
if Ausrichtung == '#' or not Ausrichtung:  
    Ausrichtung = 0.0  
  
Correct in all points?

Comment: In that case, the whole thing can be reduced to `Ausrichtung = arcpy.GetParameter(9) if arcpy.GetParameter(9) else 0.0` (all on one line), and everything from the `if` onward is only necessary if it's possible to pass in null/blank values instead of `0`.